# HTTPResponse handling invalid content type

Tags: android, json, http, httpresponse, content-type

I have the below code :

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0] + params[1]);
httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

if (httpResponse != null) {
 // do something
}
```

As you can see the content-type is application/json.

But i receive content-type as text/html, i need to check only if the response is application/json only then process.We can have with equalsIgnoreCase check but i looking for some better solution.

Comment: What's so bad about this that you need a better solution? (I don't think there is one btw)

Comment: @TimCastelijns i can have a check like this if(httpResponse.getEntity().getContentType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("application/json")){
     
    }

Comment: I assume that works fine, why are you looking for another way?

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes that works good, is there any better way to handle ? if its text/html

Comment: No this is the right way I think